# Get unique entries for Item and Date Manufactured with minimum retailer id

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with these three attributes, say:

```
ItemID varchar(20),
RetailerID int,
ItemMfd_Date DATE
```

Now I want all those records such that if there are multiple retailers for a given **`Item` + `ItemMfd_Date`** we need to pick the row that is with minimum `RetailerID`.

Suppose we have two attribute additional, and we want one more attribute as result but condition is those records must have attr2 = 1

Comment: You are always welcome to edit your question to *clarify* and *add missing information*. But please do not change the nature of the question after answers have been given. Start a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `min` aggregate function and group by the two other columns:

```
select ItemID, min(RetailerID) as min_RetailerID, ItemMfd_Date 
from table 
group by ItemID, ItemMfd_Date;
```

Comment: This is wrong , this give multiple rows for same ItemID, ItemMfd_Date

Comment: No, it doesn't unless `ItemMfd_Date` isn't a `date` but a `timestamp` value. Can you show some sample data where it gives multiple rows with the same ItemID and ItemMfd_Date?

Comment: @mat7: The query seems correct. After `group by ItemID, ItemMfd_Date`, there should be only *one*. There must be a misunderstanding.

Comment: @jpw What if suppose we have two more attributes, attr1,attr2 and we want only attr1 also with attr2 value as 1

Comment: @mat7 That is not the scenario the question described and would indeed need a different solution (like the ones suggested by Erwin). My query works for the scenario you described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT ON` is simplest to retrieve the *one* with minimum `RetailerID` row per `(ItemID, ItemMfd_Date)`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ItemID, ItemMfd_Date) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY ItemID, ItemMfd_Date, RetailerID;
```

Details:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

For distributions with *many* duplicates, other query styles may be faster:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: Is DISTINCT ON not supported by postgres SQL ?

Comment: @mat7: `DISTINCT ON` has been in Postgres *for ever*. Follow the links for details. What do you get for `SELECT version()`. Please update your question with your Postgres version and the exact table definition if the problem persists.